# asymmetric colour gradient with ggplot bin2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart which I want to colour the bin density (as below). But I want to have single bins (value=1) as black and higher values either as a single other colour, or better, as a gradient.

I have only been able to have a single black->red gradient, or completely discrete colours which is too confusing. I haven't been able to successfully map manual colours to the 'count' variable of the bin2d function. Can anyone suggest a fix?

My code:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=as.factor(V4), y=V2)) +
  geom_bin2d(binwidth = c(1,100)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="black", high="red") +
  facet_wrap(~V1, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Zoomed version, showing how difficult it is to differentiate 2s
[image]

EDIT: I've realised a better way to represent this. What I want is a scale that looks like this:
[image]

My data (x) looks like this:

```
  V1   V2 V3 V4
  5  5831 30 A
  5 20451 38 A
  5 23151 34 B
  5 30061 39 A
  5 34191 32 B
  5 41641 30 A
```

So, V2 is position of the row up the y axis, V1 is the facets and V4 is the vertical columns. Existence of the row (previously determined by V3 but not relevant here) contributes to the bin2d count.

Comment: People can be of more help if you provide example data (what's in `x`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work this out. Found that you can map to the bind count using "..count..", so the code now reads:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=as.factor(V4), y=V2)) +
  geom_bin2d(binwidth = c(1,100), aes(fill=as.factor(..count..))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000000", "#FF9900", "#FF6600", "#FF3300")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(12)) +
  facet_wrap(~V1, nrow = 1)
```